# I have a "git serve" subcommand and no idea where it comes from

Tags: git, alias, daemon

I've been trying to create a `git serve` alias for a specific `git daemon` configuration and it's never worked, but finally looking into it it looks like there's a `git serve` command somewhere which takes priority over the alias, I just have no idea where it comes from: after having removed the alias, the command still exists, but has no help, and there's no `git-serve` anywhere on the PATH.

```sh
> git serve
000eversion 2
0015agent=git/2.21.0
000cls-refs
0012fetch=shallow
0012server-option
0000^C
> git config --get alias.serve
> git serve --help
No manual entry for git-serve
> git-serve
zsh: command not found: git-serve
```

How would I even find out what this `git serve` command is and where it comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git-serve` was added last year, in Git 2.18. [It's part of a new network protocol.](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed10cb952d315ae47d2f7f6f29333a9ee227bf6b)

Git subcommands are usually not on your path. You'll probably find `git-serve` installed under `/usr/lib/git-core` or `/usr/libexec/git-core`.

Comment: Ah yes, that was the one, thank you. Annoying that it apparently has no man page, and that it conflicts with and breaks many/most of the old "instant git repository sharing" articles (which mirrored `hg serve` in their naming).